# Split excel tabs by categories and save them as separate files

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Let's say that I have .xlsx file with several sheets named like ISO3 codes:
AFG, ALB, AGO, ... , ZWE. Something around 75 tabs.

What I would like to do is to split this tabs by categories and save them as separate files.
Example:

Category 1: AFG, ALB, AGO - output Categoty_1.xlsx only with these 3 tabs.

Category 2: AZE, BGD, BEN, BNT, BOL - output Categoty_2.xlsx only with these 5 tabs
etc.

Trying to do that with `pd.ExcelWriter` but no success yet.

Comment: Could you describe what you have done? And what is the error message?

Comment: Is it a requirement to use Python? Than probably it should be part of the question. Otherwise there are plenty of other ways to achieve this, like VBA, PowerShell and lots of other libraries in other languages too, and the question could be more open about the tools to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create dictionary for new filenames with expected sheets, then use `sheet_name=None` in [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) for dictionary of `DataFrame`s and then write sheetnames in loop by dict:

```
d = {'Categoty_1': ['AFG', 'ALB', 'AGO'], 'Categoty_2':['AZE','BGD','BEN','BNT','BOL']}

dfs = pd.read_excel('inputfile.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

for k, v in d.items():
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{k}.xlsx')
    for sheet in v:
        #tested if match sheetname
        if sheet in dfs.keys():
            dfs[sheet].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet)
    writer.save()
```